# Go to previous line after scanf() in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Consider this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char a;
    printf("scan: ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("\b back");
}
```

After the user presses Enter and makes the cursor go down, I want to move it back up so I can print the word "back" overwriting the word "scan". How do I do this?

Comment: Print back or go back?

Comment: Try [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Comment: With buffered input, this may not be possible.  You may have to make a system call to clear the screen: `system("cls");`.

Comment: You don't. Just don't do that. It's not needed. The user wants to see what they have typed. There's no good way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ANSI escape sequences: `\033[<N>A`, where `<N>` would be amount of lines you need to go up (in this case, one), so code would look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(void) {
    char a;
    printf("scan: ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("%c[1A back", 033);
}
```

Also, you shouldn't declare main as `void`. Please note that escape sequences won't work in some terminals (like Windows cmd.exe or DOS without ANSI.SYS installed).

`system("cls")` would be the worst method to solve the problem, and installing ncurses only to move cursor upwards is total overkill, because you always have this simple solution i presented above.

Whenever you'll want to read more about ANSI escape sequences, check [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/c327.html). If you want to rewind cursor to end of the line, check this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(void) {
    char a;
    printf("scan: ");
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("%c[1Ascan: %c back", 033, a);
}
```

You have to recreate line contents, tho. But it shouldn't be too problematic.
It can be made easier with more advanced use of ANSI escape sequences, which you can check in link provided.

Comment: @NiPoo that's why i've mentioned that `system("cls")` is **bad** idea.

Comment: Can you look at my next answer post.. :(

Comment: Please remove that answer, it's not actually answer.
We discuss in comments only.

Comment: You are experiencing this behavior, because your terminal doesn't support ansi escapes. Alternative for windows would be ConEmu, ANSICon, or Hyper.

Comment: You.shouldn't omit the return type. Write `int main(void)`.

Comment: @n.m. just implicit int rule I'm used to.

Comment: There is no implicit int rule in C. It has been deprecated for quite some time, and now is removed for good. Please, it's not 1988 any more.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't warn you about implicit int, then either it's very old or you are not enabling common warnings. Neither of these is desirable.

Comment: @n.m. I am using C89 because it's most portable, trying to get rid of getting used to implicit int tho. std=c89 removes this warning.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk -- with `gcc -std=c89 -Wall` there is: **warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]**.

Comment: @DavidBowling idk then, gcc is not bombarding me with it.

Comment: Please fix your answer. It is incorrect as faras the C standard goes. There is only one C standard in effect, the current one. Being correct with respect to it is a requirement. Being correct with respect to obsolete editions of the standard is an added bonus. Not even speaking about using good style. Implicit int is horrible style regardless of correctness.

Comment: @n.m. OP didn't specify C standard, I can use the one I wish.
If you want to "improve" the answer, edit it.

Comment: The code doesn't work anyway so not much improvement can be made. If you insist on programming against an obsolete standard and using obsolete idioms, it's your right. Such programs were all good back in 1998, they are just non-standard and not looking good today, that's all.

Comment: The code only works for ANSI terminals, which you know and acknowledge yourself. OP is using an older Windows console, which is not an ANSI terminal, hence the code doesn't work for OP.

Comment: I have recommended him alternatives.

Comment: @Krzysztof Szewczyk What OS do you use? I'm using Windows 10 & CodeBlocks for Compiling C.